# embed pdf file from google docin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-docs

i am not looking for a plugin solution as i dont want to use a plugin just for this.i am using wordpress >4.0

i am tiring to embed a pdf file i get the embed code form google docs which is like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/laksdldjlsakdjuikjasoius/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

when i put the code in the html view of my wordpress page creator and click update the page is refreshed and the code disappeared as if wordpress is deleting the code.

the code works fine if used in another simple (non-wordpress) html page.

So what seems to be the issue.?

I dont want to host the document form my site instead i want to use the docs which i have on Google docs but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress WYSIWYG strips out some HTML tags (one of which is the `<iframe>`). See [this related post on WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes).

You can either write your own shortcode to handle iframes, or use a plugin. Either way, you're going to need to pass the `src` attribute of the iframe into the editor, without embedding it within the actual `<iframe>` tag, or modify the way TinyMCE strips out tags.